# Excel - Highlight rows that have same value on 2 cells and different in 3rd

Tags: excel, row, highlight, conditional-formatting

How can I automatically highlight in Excel all the rows that follow the following principle: B4 and B5 values are duplicate (e.g. SKU), C4 and C5 values are duplicate (e.g. Data), but H4 and H5 different.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
=AND(ROW(B1)>1, COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B1, $C:$C, $C1, $H:$H, "<>"&$H1)>1)
```

[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTe1c.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you post your data within your question (best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) it is much easier to help you.

Comment: Looks OK except that it should be >=, i.e.   =AND(ROW(B1)>1, COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B1, $C:$C, $C1, $H:$H, "<>"&$H1)>=1)